# "history" stops working when run inside bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-history

I am writing a simple script to grep my bash history to find a particular string. On the command line, I can do the following, which works fine:

```
history | grep git
```

However, when I create a bash script with the same command as above, suddenly `history` returns nothing:

```
#!/bin/bash
history | grep git
```

When I remove the first line `#!/bin/bash`, my script works again. What is happening here? How can I use `history` inside a bash script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following is for **`bash 4.0 or higher only`**, but it does the trick. :)

```
#!/bin/bash -i
history | grep sometext
```

Works! Try it out. (`-i` = **i**nteractive, a flag **not** available to bash 3.x and earlier)

Answer (score 15):

When you run a bash shell script, for example by running an executable file whose shebang line is `#!/bin/bash`, the script is run in a non-interactive shell. One of the features of a non-interactive shell is that history is disabled.
So if you want your script to be able to use history, you'd need to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history   # Or wherever you bash history file lives
set -o history             # enable history
history | grep git
```

Of course, in this case you could have just done:

```
grep git ~/.bash_history
```

Since both of the above require that the history file (`~/.bash_history`) be up to date, which it almost certainly will not be.

I'm not sure how you run your script after the shebang line is removed. Sourcing the file (eg., with `.`) is *not* the same as running the script because the commands run in the current shell, which does have history enabled.

Comment: What about doing `history -a` right after the set command to make sure the last commands are appended to the file first?

Comment: @illuminÉ: won't help. The shell started to run the script is a completely diffetent process; it starts with a frsh empty history.